# Slackware Linux: Glib can't find libffi.so.6. Where is it trying to look?

Tags: linux, libraries, glib

I have libffi installed and it's in /usr/local/lib, yet the glib make process can't find it

```
/home/mathmagi/src/glib-2.32.4/gio/.libs/lt-glib-compile-resources: error while loading shared libraries: libffi.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
/home/mathmagi/src/glib-2.32.4/gio/.libs/lt-glib-compile-resources: error while loading shared libraries: libffi.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
/home/mathmagi/src/glib-2.32.4/gio/.libs/lt-glib-compile-resources: error while loading shared libraries: libffi.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
/home/mathmagi/src/glib-2.32.4/gio/.libs/lt-glib-compile-resources: error while loading shared libraries: libffi.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
make[4]: Entering directory `/home/mathmagi/src/glib-2.32.4/gio/tests'
  GEN    gdbus-test-codegen-generated.c
  GEN    test_resources.c
/home/mathmagi/src/glib-2.32.4/gio/.libs/lt-glib-compile-resources: error while loading shared libraries: libffi.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
make[4]: *** [test_resources.c] Error 127
make[4]: Leaving directory `/home/mathmagi/src/glib-2.32.4/gio/tests'
make[3]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/mathmagi/src/glib-2.32.4/gio'
make[2]: *** [all] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/mathmagi/src/glib-2.32.4/gio'
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/mathmagi/src/glib-2.32.4'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

It's definitely in /usr/local/lib!

```
bash-4.1# updatedb
bash-4.1# locate libffi.so.6
/usr/local/lib/libffi.so.6
/usr/local/lib/libffi.so.6.0.0
/home/mathmagi/src/libffi-3.0.11/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/.libs/libffi.so.6
/home/mathmagi/src/libffi-3.0.11/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/.libs/libffi.so.6.0.0
```

With glib I've tried

```
LDFLAGS=-L/usr/local/lib ./configure
```

Doesn't work.

How do I find where glib is looking and change it?

Comment: Well, I guess I got it to work anyway.

I had /usr/local/lib set in /etc/ld.so.conf and that didn't work, but all of a sudden setting the path to LD_LIBRARY_PATH made it work.

I'm still wondering why nothing else worked.

Comment: According to output it wasn't problem of linking, but the problem with existing executable `lt-glib-copmile-resources` during its loading. That's why setting `LDFLAGS` didn't work.

Answer (score 3):

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib
```

worked for me on Debian Squeeze.

Comment: Can you please mark this as the answer to your question?

Comment: @OliverSalzburg - What file does this line go into?

Comment: @dieKleene: I only edited this answer, but I would assume it's supposed to be an environment variable. Set it like `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib`